# Change primary key to auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I updated my database schema in Doctrine 2 / Sf2 and added some new tables to my database. Everything was going okay, but when I wanted to create the admin side of the application I realized that I need some IDs to be AUTO_INCREMENT.

Then, I wanted to change my schema. From this.

```
X\XBundle\Entity\Currency:
type: entity
table: currencies
repositoryClass: CurrencyRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 64
manyToMany:
    brokers:
        targetEntity: X\XBundle\Entity\Broker
        mappedBy: currencies
```

To this:

```
X\XBundle\Entity\Currency:
type: entity
table: currencies
repositoryClass: CurrencyRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO } # I changed on this row!
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 64
manyToMany:
    brokers:
        targetEntity: X\XBundle\Entity\Broker
        mappedBy: currencies
```

Then I tried to run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` in CLI and got this message:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_706E39538248176' of table 'forexcbc.broker_currencies'
```

I tried everything now. I deleted the foreign keys manually and rerun the script, didn't work. I deleted the relations between the two tables, didn't work. And the funny thing is, there is nothing in the tables yet.

My Broker schema looks like this (I don't know if this is helping in any form)

```
X\XBundle\Entity\Broker:
type: entity
table: brokers
repositoryClass: BrokerRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 64
oneToMany:
    accountTypes:
        targetEntity: X\XBundle\Entity\AccountType
        mappedBy: broker
        cascade: ["persist"]
manyToMany:
    currencies:
        targetEntity: X\XBundle\Entity\Currency
        inversedBy: brokers
        joinTable:
            name: broker_currencies
            joinColumns:
                broker_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                currency_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

My question is, how on Earth is it possible to set the ID field to auto increment after the tables were created. Again, there is nothing in the tables yet.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying the update to the database, you can dump the SQL to be applied:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete
```

Open a mysql shell, select your DB and first disable foreign key checks:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Then execute the generated SQL queries in the shell.

When you're done, close the shell, and run the `doctrine:schema:update` command again, to see if everything was successful.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! Just for the record, if you only disable foreign keys with SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 and then run schema:update it won't work. Because schema:update re-enables foreign keys automatically.

Comment: Actually, the reason is that `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` only affects the current connection. The moment you close your MySQL connection and open a new one, key checks are on again.